# railstutorial 10.3.1: undefined local variable or method `microposts_path', `micropost_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, railstutorial.org

Have a problem with testing in [10.3.1 Access control](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts?version=3.2#sec-access_control):

```
    Failures:

    1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the destroy action 
 Failure/Error: before { delete micropost_path(FactoryGirl.create(:micropost)) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `micropost_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_2:0x00000004edd970>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:117:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'

    2) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users in the Microposts controller submitting to the create action 
 Failure/Error: before { post microposts_path }
 NameError:
   undefined local variable or method `microposts_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3::Nested_3::Nested_1::Nested_3::Nested_1:0x0000000521c758>
 # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:112:in `block (6 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I add in `routes.rb` this:

```
 resources :misroposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

But it don't help. What means `undefined method 'micropost_path'`? I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have the line `resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]` in your `routes.rb`? Check out [Listing 10.22](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#code-microposts_resource).

That will create two named routes, `microposts_path` (accessible with a `POST` request) and `micropost_path` (accessible with a `DELETE` request), which you can see (along with all the other paths in your app) if you type `rake routes` into the console.

Check out [Table 7.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#table-RESTful_users) of the tutorial - that's what happens when you add `resources :users` to `routes.rb`.

`Resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]` would work the same way, except, of course, you would only get the `create` and `destroy` actions, as explained in [Table 10.2](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/user-microposts#table-RESTful_microposts).

Comment: Sorry, I put in question else line. Yes, I have `resources :misroposts, only: [:create, :destroy]`. `rake routes` have paths:
`misroposts POST   /misroposts(.:format)     misroposts#create`
`misropost DELETE /misroposts/:id(.:format) misroposts#destroy`

Comment: Oh, it looks like you have a typo. It should say `microposts` with a c, not `misroposts` with an s.

Comment: Happens to me all the time! :)